# OpenCl with github actions in windows

Tags: opencl, github-actions

I have a Windows c++ project that uses OpenCl gpu library. I would like to build the project in github actions, but I do not have any idea how to install OpenCl deveopment libraries in githubactions (in Linux I can simply install the library using apt package manager)? Locally I have installed this OpenCl library [OCL-SDK](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases) and set the OPENCL_ROOT environment variable (however any OpenCl development library is fine). Is there a way to build OpenCl dependent c++ windows project in github actions?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub hosts Linux and Windows runners on Standard_DS2_v2 virtual machines, which don't have GPU support. [Here's the hardware specs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources) for Github's Windows and Linux virtual machines. As far as I'm aware, if you want to use Github actions for a Windows project with OpenCL, you either need to set up a self-hosted runner or add the required OpenCL library files to your repo.